# url of second button needs two clicks to return?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

My app has two buttons that each open different webpages.
Each button references an onClick event and Intent that
differs only in the URL. The main and webview activity are below.
The second button, however, requires
two clicks to return to the main view. How can I fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;
private Button button1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("google.com", "http://www.google.com");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);             
            intent.putExtra("yahoo.com", "http://www.yahoo.com");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }

}
```

**WebviewActivity**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
        String googleUrl = extras.getString("google.com");
        String yahooUrl = extras.getString("yahoo.com");
    if (googleUrl != null)
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    else if (yahooUrl != null)
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
    }
}

main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go to http://www.google.com" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go to http://www.yahoo.com" />

</LinearLayout>

webview.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: What happens when you click back button once?

Comment: Clicking "return" from the second URL, causes a white screen to appear. A second "return" will get back to the main layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The second url could be redirecting somewhere like http://google.com  -> http://google.com/en/.  This would however require two fast clicks. since after the first click, it would redirect again.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the second URL from www.yahoo.com to www.wikipedia.com, but the same behavior occurs. The second page returns to a blank screen and then needs a second click to go to home.

Answer (score 0):

can you post you xml? And why two OnClickListener ? your class can implement one OnClickListener  and based on id of resource you can differentiate. Also you can start a thread for starting activity instead of blocking .

Comment: Thanks, I added the two xml layouts.  I tried one onClickListerner, but the second button did not work:                                      public void onClick()                                                     { Intent intent = new Intent...; intent.putExtra(1st); intent.putExtra(2nd); startActivity(intent); ...